Django Chatroom model: Retrieve latest messages from all rooms a user is part of
I'm having a hard time constructing a query (sqlite) to get the latest message for each chatroom a user is part of. This is my model in Django:
class Membership(models.Model):
    room_name = models.TextField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, through="Message")

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    advertisement = models.ForeignKey(Advertisement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)

Now with this in mind I would like to display all rooms a user is part of and additionally the latest message in a room. I feel like I'm close:
select *
from chat_message as cm
inner join (select max(id) as lm from chat_message group by room_id) as last_messages on last_messages.lm = cm.id
inner join main_advertisement ma on cm.advertisement_id = ma.id
inner join chat_membership as cmb ON cm.room_id = cmb.id
order by id;

Which looks like this gives me the latest messages (and other data) for each room but now I struggle to filter for just 1 user (e.g. user_id = 3).
Any ideas would be appreciated, also for possible hints how to start constructing this in the django ORM.

You can add a filter to your inner query where you get the maximum chat_message ids:
select *
from chat_message as cm
inner join (select max(id) as lm from chat_message where user_id = 3 group by room_id) as last_messages on last_messages.lm = cm.id
inner join main_advertisement ma on cm.advertisement_id = ma.id
inner join chat_membership as cmb ON cm.room_id = cmb.id
order by id;

You can get the last message of a user for each room, defaulting to the very last message if the user has not written a message there yet as follows:
select the_message.*, main_advertisement.*, chat_membership.*
from chat_message the_message
left join chat_message better_message
on the_message.room_id = better_message.room_id and (((the_message.user_id <> 3) and (better_message.user_id = 3)) or (((the_message.user_id = 3) = (better_message.user_id = 3)) and (the_message.id < better_message.id)))
inner join main_advertisement on the_message.advertisement_id = main_advertisement.id
inner join chat_membership on the_message.room_id = chat_membership.id
where better_message.room_id is null

Explanation:

we get the_message
and we search for better_message
if there is no better_message than the_message, as checked for in the where clause, then we found the_message we searched for
otherwise we ignore the_message
the_message has a better_message pair if and only if they belong to the same room. the_message does not belong to the user we search for and better_message belongs to him/her, OR they are both either belonging to this user or not belonging to him/her, but better_message has a greater id
we join main_advertisement and chat_membership to the_message
we ignore rooms where there are no messages yet

EDIT
Added a room name filter to make sure the user is member of the room:
select the_message.*, main_advertisement.*, chat_membership.*
from chat_message the_message
left join chat_message better_message
on the_message.room_id = better_message.room_id and (((the_message.user_id <> 3) and (better_message.user_id = 3)) or (((the_message.user_id = 3) = (better_message.user_id = 3)) and (the_message.id < better_message.id)))
inner join main_advertisement on the_message.advertisement_id = main_advertisement.id
inner join chat_membership on the_message.room_id = chat_membership.id and CONCAT(room_name, '_%') like '%_3_%'
where better_message.room_id is null


Thank you! I tried this too but unfortunately this results in the last_message only for the user_id = 3. The last_message could also be from somebody else
I feel like it needs another subselect inside the subselect.
Should I create a DB fiddle to explain this better?

@gary my current understanding is that you want to get a message from each room which would be the last message of the given user if the user has at least a message there and defaulting to the very last message in the room if the user has not written a message there yet.

@gary I have edited my answer and added a new query that finds the best message for each room, the best message being the last message of the given user if the user has written a message there, but if the user has not written there, then the latest message by any user there.

Thanks, your edit is closer but to better visualize this I created this db fiddle
The problem with the edited query is that it returns also last message from chat the user_id = 3 is not part of. see last column room_name, its chat_3_1, chat_3_2 (both correct) but should not return result chat_1_2 since user is not part of it

@gary I see. You can infer the members of a room by the name of the room, such as chat_3_2. So you can add a new criteria, like and CONCAT(room_name, '_%') like '%_3_%' which will search for 3 inside a text that starts with your room_name and ends with _ to solve issues such as 13 containing 3 is not to be considered a match. You can add this criteria to the chat_membership join condition.

thank you. I tried all day now and I believe I got the correct solution now: Updated db fiddle.
